# Can multiple instances of QThread refer to the same OS thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt5, qthread

I am using `QThread` as a manager of threads, and I am wondering if it is possible to instanciate multiple `QThread` objects that all manage the same thread?

Answer (score 1):

No, of course.

A single thread can be managed by only 1 QThread because it will be created internally inside `void QThread::start(Priority)`, there're noway to set the thread to `QThread`

From [`qthread_unix.cpp`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/thread/qthread_unix.cpp#n645)

```
int code = pthread_create(&threadId, &attr, QThreadPrivate::start, this);
```

[`pthread_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) will start a new thread.

From [`qthread_win.cpp`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/thread/qthread_win.cpp#n495)

```
#if defined(Q_CC_MSVC) && !defined(_DLL) // && !defined(Q_OS_WINRT)
#  ifdef Q_OS_WINRT
    // If you wish to accept the memory leaks, uncomment the part above.
    // See:
    //  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/104641
    //  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx
#    error "Microsoft documentation says this combination leaks memory every time a thread is started. " \
    "Please change your build back to -MD/-MDd or, if you understand this issue and want to continue, " \
    "edit this source file."
#  endif
    // MSVC -MT or -MTd build
    d->handle = (Qt::HANDLE) _beginthreadex(NULL, d->stackSize, QThreadPrivate::start,
                                            this, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &(d->id));
#else
    // MSVC -MD or -MDd or MinGW build
    d->handle = (Qt::HANDLE) CreateThread(NULL, d->stackSize, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)QThreadPrivate::start,
                                            this, CREATE_SUSPENDED, reinterpret_cast<LPDWORD>(&d->id));
#endif // Q_OS_WINRT
```

Both [`CreateThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms682453.aspx) and [`_beginthreadex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx) will create a new thread, of course.

Comment: But I have in my program gotten hold of different pointers to QThread object using QOject::QThread() but they all return same handle, indicating they are in fact managing same thread. How is this possible?

Comment: To clarify; with handle I mean returnvalue from QThread::currenthThreadId()

Comment: @LennartRolland Do you mean [`QObject::thread`] function? That function return a pointer to `QThread` in which the object lives. Since most of your object will lives in the main thread, it will return the **same pointer**, it means it's the **same `QThread`**